# How can I represent powers and exponents such as Unicode character 'superscript two" in FXML/XML?

Tags: xml, unicode, utf-8, javafx-8, fxml

My FXML file is formatted in UTF-8.
This is the relevant part of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Text fx:id="totalSqMGlassText" layoutX="573.0" layoutY="547.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="&#x0xB2;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="57.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="573.0" />
```

I checked the UTF-8 code for second power [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm) and [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024&unicodeinhtml=dec&htmlent=1). Found this information about Unicode character "superscript two", i.e. the second power: "UTF-8 (hex) - 0xC2 0xB2 (c2b2)". I also read this question and answer on [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016202/using-unicode-characters-with-javafx). So I tried with these:
`&#x0xC2;`
`e&#x0xB2;`
`&#xc2b2;`
`&#c2b2;`
and even this :)
`&#c2 b2;`

If I use standard text everything works fine but if I try with the aforementioned special character and escaping I receive this exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
```

...
`Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[142,121]
Message: The character reference must end with the ';' delimiter.`

or this

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at
```

`[row,col]:[142,118]` 
`Message: A decimal representation must immediately follow the "&#" in a character reference.`

Each time I used semicolon (once I tried even without semicolon and with two semicolons :)).
I think the second exception is obvious. In my desperation I simply tried  few times to enter the right escaping blindly so I used escaping for decimal representation instead for hexadecimal (correct me if I'm wrong). 
So my question is:

Do you know what am i doing wrong and what is the right escaping and code in that situation? And also what is the right way to represent powers and exponents through FXML/XML in general? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `&#x0xB2;` with `&#xb2;` for Unicode `SUPERSCRIPT TWO` (²).