# How to display non-ascii characters in JavaFX GUI programs?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, unicode, ascii

I was working on my newest project using JavaFX and I've recently run into a problem that I can't seem to find the solution to. I want to display non-ascii characters on buttons, text labels, etc. But there is just no documentation on how to do it. How do I do that?

Comment: Just use the Unicode escape for your desired character. Assuming you're using FXML rather than programmatic layouts, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016202/using-unicode-characters-with-javafx).

Answer (score -1):

https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~zben/Web/CharSet/htmlchars.html

IDE might not Support Those Characters
Just Copy past them Directly on buttons inside FXML SceneBuilder

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Av7.png)